# Properties and tryparse

Tags: c#

I have a class with 3 properties, and I would like to know how I can write my code better. I want to use `Single.TryParse` so that if any token is unknown string, I could still get `0`. But using this method, I need to use a temp variable, and as my properties list increases, I will have more temp variable, and this is not efficient. Is there any way to code this better?

```
public class GSA : NMEAMsg
{
    public float Pdop { set; get; }
    public float Hdop { set; get; }
    public float Vdop { set; get; }

    protected override void parseTokens(string[] tokens)
    {
        float pdop = 0;
        float hdop = 0;
        float vdop = 0;

        Single.TryParse(tokens[tokens.Length - 3], out pdop);
        Single.TryParse(tokens[tokens.Length - 2], out hdop);
        Single.TryParse(tokens[tokens.Length - 1], out vdop);

        Pdop = pdop;
        Hdop = hdop;
        Vdop = vdop;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are all these acronyms for? What's the context? Feel free to [edit] and add a snippet showing us the code that's interacting with this class. Tell us *why* you need this code in your project, and *why* you're expecting the number of properties to increase.

Comment: i am creating a nmea message (GPS) parser, i have some NMEA msg like (GPGGA) it has many properties that i need to use `tryparse`, i am just thinking of is there any better way to do this or none?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *I have a class with 3 properties, [...] and as my properties list increases, [...]*

Wait, stop - here, that.

Classes are the blueprint for an *object* - the *public members* are that object's *interface*, and that shouldn't need to change that way. The *Open/Closed Principle* tells us that classes should be opened for *extension*, and closed for modification.

I don't know what any of these members mean, but a design that needs to change all the time is a design that didn't integrate the *need to change* as a requirement.

A design that *embraces change*, is one that minimizes the amount of code that's required to add to extend a piece of existing functionality.

If, instead of saying "I need a class with a `P`, `H` and `V` 'dop' float values, and maybe a `X`, `Y` and `Z` too, eventually", you said "I need a class with an unknown bunch of 'dop' float values; for this version I'll have `P`, `H` and `V` values, nobody knows what future holds"... the design would have reflected that.

> ```
> void parseTokens(string[] tokens)
> ```

You have a `string[]` array here, an `IEnumerable<string>` ready to play with: *use it to your advantage*, and ask yourself how you could possibly structure things so that `parseTokens` (which should really be `ParseTokens` - *conventions FTW!*) can be implemented with an *iterative logic*.

Consider an enum:

```
public enum Dop // whatever that means
{
    Pdop,
    Hdop,
    Vdop
}
```

To add support for a new property, you add an enum member. Then you can have a function that returns this:

```
return tokens
    .Select((value, index) =>
        {
            float dop; 
            var success = float.TryParse(value, out dop); 
            return new 
            {
                Key = (Dop)index, 
                Success = success, 
                Value = dop
            };
        })
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Success ? item.Value : (float?)null);
```

Notice `float.TryParse` is the same as `Single.TryParse`.

That's a `Dictionary<Dop,float?>`, where the `float?` value is `null` when the string couldn't be parsed into a `float`; you would take that and assign it to a `private readonly` field.

That's nice, but a `Dictionary` is not exactly the type of data structure you usually want to expose in your public interface - how about an indexer?

```
public float? this[Dop dop]
{
    get
    {
        float? value;
        return _tokens.TryGetValue(dop, out value)
            ? value
            : null;
     }
}
```

<sub>(assuming `private readonly IDictionary<Dop,float?> _tokens;` assigned in constructor)</sub>

That said, I'd like to bring your attention to the indexing here:

> ```
> Single.TryParse(tokens[tokens.Length - 3], out pdop);
> Single.TryParse(tokens[tokens.Length - 2], out hdop);
> Single.TryParse(tokens[tokens.Length - 1], out vdop);
> ```

Whenever `tokens` has less than the expected number of items, things blow up. What's the index of the `pdop` value in the `tokens` array? As a maintainer you shouldn't have to be bothered with these riddles.

What does using an enum get us? Imagine the client code has an instance of a `GSA` class, named `gsa`:

```
var pdop = gsa[Dop.Pdop];
var hdop = gsa[Dop.Hdop];
var vdop = gsa[Dop.Vdop];
```

If `gsa` has a float value for `Pdop`, then `pdop` will contain that value. Otherwise, it will be `null`.

And to extend it, you now only need to do this:

```
public enum Dop
{
    Pdop,
    Hdop,
    Vdop,
    Xdop,
    Ydop,
    Zdop
}
```

...and make sure the `tokens` array provided has as many arguments / *fail fast*:

```
protected override void ParseTokens(string[] tokens)
{
    if (tokens.Length != Enum.GetNames(typeof(Dop)).Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of tokens.");
    }

    //
}
```

---

Another thing that strikes me as *not needed* and potentially bug-prone, is exposing the setters for these hard-earned float values.

Also, the order of the accessors is unusual:

> ```
> public float Pdop { set; get; }
> ```

I'm used to see the getter first.

```
public float Pdop { get; private set; }
```

With a private setter, the only way to set that value is to parse a new array of strings.

At this point I'd question the mutability of the type. How about simply this?

```
public class GSA : NMEAMsg
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Dop,float?> _tokens;

    public GSA(string[] tokens)
    {
        if (tokens.Length != Enum.GetNames(typeof(Dop)).Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of tokens.");
        }

        _tokens = tokens
            .Select((value, index) =>
                {
                    float dop; 
                    var success = float.TryParse(value, out dop); 
                    return new 
                    {
                        Key = (Dop)index, 
                        Success = success, 
                        Value = dop
                    };
                })
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Success ? item.Value : (float?)null);
    }

    public float? this[Dop dop]
    {
        get
        {
            float? value;
            return _tokens.TryGetValue(dop, out value)
                ? value
                : null;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! a very nice approach i dint think of! and thanks for all the tips!   :)